# return database value in node

Tags: mysql, node.js

can you please help me, I try to return the value of "result" to save it in "subject" but it does not return anything to me and if I put it back out the result does not work either

```
            function solicitud() {

                client.query('SELECT solicitud FROM solicitud WHERE cod_solicitud = 5',(err, result)=>{
                    if(err){
                        return console.error('error de solicitudes', err);
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;
                });
            }
            subject = solicitud();
```

Comment: `client.query` is aync operation. It will not work like this. In 2018 use async await. Does your `console.log(result);` produces right output?

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy the console works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your function should look something like this:

```
async function solicitud() {
  try {
    const res = await client.query('SELECT solicitud FROM solicitud WHERE cod_solicitud = 5');
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
     throw new Error('error de solicitudes');
  }  
}                   
const subject = await solicitud();
```

Comment: gave me this error friend.
subject = await request ();
Unexpected identifier

Comment: Yes, you have to use es6. And await keyword can only be inside async function. In other words, whole this code must be wrapped in function with `async` keyword. You have to learn async await. But this is separate question.